# Face loop select options. Selecting faces between two faces

Tags: modeling, faces, selection-tools, loop

When I clicked Alt and select the face its select all the faces in the horizontal direction [image: Alt Select], which is not not what I required I want to select the faces in the vertical direction. Is there anyway to do it. In other software I can shift select two faces and the faces in between automatically gets selected.
How can it be done in Blender?

Comment: Also, Ctrl-clicking a face  will select all the faces on the shortest route between the clicked face and the last selected face

Comment: Thanks Robin Belts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose the direction the loop select will go, you should be in face selection and alt select an edge in the direction you want the edge loop to go. If you want it to go vertical then alt select the top edge while in face selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It solved my problem